# Nested aggregation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have Elasticsearch documents for products with tags. Following is the structure of the documents:

```
{
    "id": 'id-1',
    "name: "prod-1",
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": 'tag-id-1',
            "name": 'tag-name-1'
        },
        {
            "id": 'tag-id-2',
            "name": 'tag-name-2'
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is:

1. Get all products with maximum overlapping tags (something like related questions in stackoverflow, assuming they have stored questions in Elasticsearch with tags). Output something like this:

   ```
   {
       "aggregations": {
           "products": [
               {
                   "key": "product-name-1",
                   "tags": [
                       {
                           "key": "tag-name-1",
                       }
                       {
                           "key": "tag-name-2"
                       }
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "key": "product-name-2",
                   "tags": [
                       {
                           "key": "tag-name-2",
                       }
                       {
                           "key": "tag-name-3"
                       }
                   ]
               },
           ]
       }
   }
   ```
2. Get all tags grouped together with a tag maximum number of times.

   ```
   {
       "aggregations": {
           "tags": [
               {
                   "key": "tag-name-1",
                   "tags": [
                       {
                           "key": "tag-name-2",
                       }
                       {
                           "key": "tag-name-3"
                       }
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "key": "product-name-2",
                   "tags": [
                       {
                           "key": "tag-name-1",
                       }
                       {
                           "key": "tag-name-5"
                       }
                   ]
               },
           ]
       }
   }
   ```

I am not very sure which type of aggregation methods to use. Any help will be useful.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share the sample output you want

Comment: @Richa: I have updated the question.

Comment: I don't think your output sample explains much.. What do you mean by overlapping tags? In second output, you have one  tag key and one product key. This is not possible.

Comment: @Richa 2nd one I thought that it is not possible. Example of overlapping tags: This questions is having two tags `elasticsearch` and `elasticsearch-2.0`. So all questions which are having both the tags should come first, then questions having either of the tags should come (along with the tags).
I hope its clear.